# Is there a quick way to indent large amounts of code?

Tags: python, indentation

I was streamlining my code by functionalizing(yes, I know it's wrong, but I call it that..), and I realized that I had about 100 lines of code to indent. My question is, is there a quick way to indent large blocks of code in python.(IDLE editor, and keyboard shortcut if possible.)

Thanks for your help, question finished!

Comment: Select the 100 lines and hit `tab` - what happens depends on your IDE. PyCharm e.g. will indent the all 100 lines by exactly one level, other python IDE's as well, as far as I remember.

Comment: Which editor are you using? Any good one will make this trivial.

Comment: In emacs you could select the lines then press Ctrl-Alt-% (regexp-replace region) and replace `^` with `    ` and then select `!` (replace all). Normally I just do ordinary regex replace, but then I have to answer `y` for only those lines that I want to indent (which is a lot if it's 100 lines). Would prefer it were simplier.

Comment: @skyking: C-u 4 C-x TAB indents everything in the region 4 spaces further, use -4 to go the other direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Sublime Text, you can do `ctrl + ]` to indent a highlighted block of text, and likewise `ctrl + [` to unindent. It's `cmd` for OSX users.

You can also do a reindent to make the entire code look pretty. `Edit → Line → Reindent`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to indent a python file, [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8) will do it for you.

```
pip install --upgrade autopep8
```

Then

```
autopep8 --in-place path/to/file
```

Comment: That assumes that the code is already "correctly" indented. My understanding was that he cut-and-pastes code that may result in syntactically invalid indentation (fx no indentation after `if` and similar).

Comment: skyking is correct, I was copypasting my own code and found that I had 100 lines to indent.

Answer (score 0):

Many editors have functions for that. The editor integrated in idle has: Format / Indent region and Format / Dedent region

Comment: Thanks, worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try of [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), which can help you to indent your code. Detailed features about PyCharm can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/)